# Javascript error custom function to enter data into form field

Tags: javascript, php

List of products displayed from database using PHP.  When product selected javascript function called to enter product into HMTL form field.

```
<div id="addProductPanel">
 <div class="popularProduct">Popular products</div>
 <div class="closeButton" onclick="closePopularProductWindow()">X</div>
 <?php
 $query_popular_product="SELECT product_code FROM database_table GROUP BY product_code ORDER BY product_code DESC";
      $result_popular_product = $link->query($query_popular_product);
      while($row = $result_popular_product->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product_code = $row['product_code'];
        echo '<div class="popularProduct" onclick="setProduct("'.$product_code.'")">'.$product_code.'</div>';
      }
 ?>
</div>
```

The js function setProduct is:

```
function setProduct(product) {
    console.log(product);
    document.getElementsByName("product")[0].value = product;
    document.getElementById("addProductPanel").style.display = "none";
}
```

When loading the page and using Chrome inspector console, selecting a product doesn't print the product in the console and produces the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` with HTML displayed as below:

```
<div class="popularProduct" onclick="setProduct("PROD123")">PROD123</div>
```

I have tried typing the following HTML and this works successfully with the javascript function:

```
<div class="popularProduct" onclick="setProduct('PROD123')">PROD123</div>
```

Cannot get the PHP syntax working with the product values from the database.

Comment: Have you tried single quotes in `"PROD123"`?

Comment: Thanks brombeer.  Yes tried single quotes in `PROD123` unfortunately this gives `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string ".$product_code.", expecting "," or ";" in`

Comment: I have tried hard coding without the PHP from database and it works ! Edit in the original question above.  I can't get it working with the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
echo '<div class="popularProduct" onclick="setProduct(\''.$product_code.'\')">'.$product_code.'</div>';
```

The double quotes will terminate the double quotes from `onclick="setProduct(...`

(Single quotes inside single quotes need to be escaped, so use `\'`)

Comment: Nice, glad it works